# Pivot rows into columns Firebird 2.1

Tags: sql, pivot, pivot-table, firebird, firebird2.1

I have a table containing several kilometers about 100
[table of kilometers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ12M.png)

I need to rotate rows into columns like this
[pivot rows into columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0Hxc.png)

1. The number of columns is fixed in rows = 10
2. Kilometers can be repeated and have gaps, for exemple: 263, 263, 264, 265, 270..

I think to use "with recursive", but there are few examples on the net (
I would be very grateful if you could help me solve the problem!

Comment: This seems purely a presentation matter, which is better and easier to solve in your presentation layer. As an aside, Firebird 2.1 has been end-of-life since 2014, you really should upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I usually use FB3.0, but the transition to a new version for users using our program is very difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, this is probably something better solved in your presentation layer, instead of through a query. I'm not sure if this can be solved with a (recursive) CTE, but I can offer you a solution in PSQL using `EXECUTE BLOCK` (this can also be done in the form of a stored procedure).

This solution maps rows to columns, and starts a new row when all columns have been filled.

```sql
execute block
returns (km_1 smallint, km_2 smallint, km_3 smallint, km_4 smallint, km_5 smallint,
  km_6 smallint, km_7 smallint, km_8 smallint, km_9 smallint, km_10 smallint)
as
  declare column_count smallint = 1;
  declare km smallint;
begin
  for select km from kms order by km into km do
  begin
    -- map value to column
    if (column_count = 1) then km_1 = km;
    else if (column_count = 2) then km_2 = km;
    else if (column_count = 3) then km_3 = km;
    else if (column_count = 4) then km_4 = km;
    else if (column_count = 5) then km_5 = km;
    else if (column_count = 6) then km_6 = km;
    else if (column_count = 7) then km_7 = km;
    else if (column_count = 8) then km_8 = km;
    else if (column_count = 9) then km_9 = km;
    else if (column_count = 10) then km_10 = km;
    
    if (column_count < 10) then
      column_count = column_count + 1;
    else
    begin
      -- row complete, output
      column_count = 1;
      suspend;
    end
  end
  if (column_count > 1) then
  begin
    -- partial row
    while (column_count <= 10) do
    begin
      -- null remaining columns
      if (column_count = 2) then km_2 = null;
      else if (column_count = 3) then km_3 = null;
      else if (column_count = 4) then km_4 = null;
      else if (column_count = 5) then km_5 = null;
      else if (column_count = 6) then km_6 = null;
      else if (column_count = 7) then km_7 = null;
      else if (column_count = 8) then km_8 = null;
      else if (column_count = 9) then km_9 = null;
      else if (column_count = 10) then km_10 = null;
      column_count = column_count + 1;
    end
    -- output partial row
    suspend;
  end
end
```

In Firebird 4.0 you can achieve the same result with window functions.

```sql
with col_row as (
  select 
    km, 
    mod(row_number() over(order by km) - 1, 10) as column_group, 
    (row_number() over(order by km) - 1) / 10 row_group
  from kms
)
select 
  min(km) filter (where column_group = 0),
  min(km) filter (where column_group = 1),
  min(km) filter (where column_group = 2),
  min(km) filter (where column_group = 3),
  min(km) filter (where column_group = 4),
  min(km) filter (where column_group = 5),
  min(km) filter (where column_group = 7),
  min(km) filter (where column_group = 8),
  min(km) filter (where column_group = 9)
from col_row
group by row_group
```

For Firebird 3.0, replace `min(km) filter (where column_group = n)` with `min(decode(column_group, n, km))` or `min(case when column_group = n then km)` (where n is 0, 1, .., 9).

Comment: Thanks Mark for the detailed answer! I’m grateful for that